# Laravel website on a shared webhost that does not provide any shell?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have a laravel 5 site on my localhost. I want to launch it on a shared host but the host is neither providing me with the shell nor it has composer installed. Can I still launch my website on this host? If yes then how? If the answer is no then what should I do?

Comment: I would recommend you to use Laravel Forge hosting, it works perfectly for Laravel websites. https://forge.laravel.com/

Comment: You should a virtual machine / dedicated server with shell access. A hacky workaround would just be copying your entire folder, including the vendor folder.

Comment: No shell access = get a new host. Your life will simply be too much trouble without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload via file manager if you wish. Follow below steps

1. Check the server configuration of PHP 5.4 (this because every little change on .htaccess file may change that config)
2. Create a directory in the same level of public_html and put your project inside that folder (except public folder).
3. Put the content of public (L5) directly on public_html (don't overwrite the .htaccess file)

Inside  `public_html` all files of public directory of Laravel 5 resides now.

Go to index.php and edit the line 22

```
#From this
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
#To this
require __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and on line 36

```
#From this 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
#To this
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then edit the `.htaccess` file and add some lines

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Hope this works. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can but you need to upload your local directory after a `composer install`, including `vendor` and `.env` using and FTP client. I wouldn't recommend it though, it makes development really hard. Maybe look into a paas like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to get you started for free.

You also need to make sure that the shared hosting supports the following:

- PHP >= 5.5.9
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension

as take from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/)